# Need help to change file format after the users download it from Database

Tags: c#

Did I miss something in this code?  cuz when I test it I get the file type as "File" not as PDF.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString1"].ConnectionString); 
    conn.Open();
    string pdffile = "select pdf from users where ID='" + TextBoxLic.Text + "'";
    SqlCommand pdfcom = new SqlCommand(pdffile, conn);
    SqlDataReader reader = pdfcom.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.Read())
    {
        Byte[] pdfData = (byte[])reader.GetValue(0);
        Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";            
        Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + TextBoxLic.Text);
        Response.BinaryWrite(pdfData);
        Response.End();
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

https://i.gyazo.com/8eb75d4e55bed17155690531841d80c7.png

Comment: You have a SQL Injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try adding a

`Response.Flush();
 Response.Close();`

after `Response.BinaryWrite(pdfData);`

More importantly it should be 
`while (reader.Read())`
rather than 
`if (reader.Read())`

I'd suggest you read up on here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: still same file type :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `Content-Type` header to `application/pdf`.

Comment: I did but still nothing changed :(

Comment: MIME types are case-sensitive.  That should be all-lowercase.

Comment: the type file didn't change :(